# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with three columns. I have to perform a mapping on last recent k records of the dataframe based on a groupBy condition. Here is the code that I wrote and it is throwing NotSerializable Exception The dataframe looks like below I have to group by them using cities and have to compute value on the last two records for every city.

```
<pre><code>
    +------------+-----+-----+
    |      cities|temps|preas|
    +------------+-----+-----+
    |   Hyderabad|   30|    3|
    |Secunderabad|   38|    3|
    |      Mumbai|   41|    4|
    |     Chennai|   39|    3|
    |      Mumbai|   25|    2|
    |     Chennai|   21|    2|
    |   Hyderabad|   36|    3|
    |secunderabad|   32|    3| 
    |     Chennai|   26|    2| 
    |      Mumbai|   45|    4|
    |     Chennai|   20|    2|
    |   Hyderabad|   39|    3|
    |Secunderabad|   42|    4|
    +------------+-----+-----+

`   import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
    val k = 2
    @transient val w = Window.partitionBy("cities") 
    val coll = List("cities","temps","preas")
    val cl = coll.map(a => col(a))
    val colls = cl :+ row_number.over(w).as("row_number")
    @transient val nums = df.select(colls:_*)
    val limits 
    =nums.groupBy("cities").agg(max($"row_number").minus(k).as("limit"))
    val data = nums.join(limits, "cities").filter($"row_number".gt($"limit"))
    val 
    dfd=data.withColumn("row_number",$"row_number".minus($"limit")).select(cl:_*)
    val dfRDD = dfd.rdd
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    val weights = List(1,2)
    val func = (it:Iterable[Row]) => {
        val lis = it.toList
        var res :List[Int] = List()
        val len = lis(0).size
        for (i<-1 until len){
          res = res:+lis.map(a=>a(i)).map(b=>b.asInstanceOf[Int]).zip(weights).map(c=>c._1*c._2).sum/(weights.reduce(_+_))
        }
        res
    }
    val outp = dfRDD.groupBy(row => row(0)).map{case(k,v)=>(k,func(v))`
```

Comment: Where is the code located in your source code? Is this a part of a method? How do you use it in the code? Show the context where the piece of code is used, please.

Comment: I am running it on command line, this is not part of any method.

Comment: You should avoid such code where you `val dfRDD = dfd.rdd`. It's not clear why you did so and am sure you will not remember it in a month either. I don't see where the exception could get thrown either. Can you paste the entire stack trace?

Comment: @wenky: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing a similar problem.